# Spring webapp returning 404 intermittently for vendor.js, vendor.css, main.css and main.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-status-code-404, intermittent

I have spring webapp and its single-page React application. While loading the page in browser I see requests for downloading vendor.js, vendor.css, main.css and main.js are failing randomly. Few resources are downloaded successfully while few return 404. Next time I refresh the page, the resource that returned 404 earlier may get loaded. Confirmed the behaviour from different machines and browsers.

Can someone please guide on resolving this issue?

Comment: Please post your code and error messages. Your description is too vague to understand the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SAUJ, and Community, Apologies.. i work in a firm where I am not allowed to share the code. I am getting error code 404 randomly on web page first load for resources vendor.js, vendor.css, main.css and main.js. I can confirm these files are present in webear under right hierarchy.